# PyCharm subclass navigation "cannot find declaration to go to"

Tags: python, autocomplete, tensorflow, pycharm

When using the TensorFlow library in PyCharm Mac, I can't go to some class implementations. For example,

```
import tensorflow as tf
classifier=tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                        hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
                                        n_classes=3,
                                        model_dir="models/iris_model")
```

When I try to go to the implementation of DNNClassifier it can't find it. But when I do

```
from tensorflow.contrib.learn import DNNClassifier
classifier = DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                        hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
                                        n_classes=3,
                                        model_dir="models/iris_model")
```

It works fine. I am not sure why PyCharm doesn't see the DNNClassifer they way it was written in the first example above.

Thanks

Comment: With a fresh install of python and tensorflow, your code on top works fine for me in a vanilla python console, so it seems the issue is with pycharm install?

Comment: Thanks Shan for checking. I am going to try reinstalling PyCharm

Comment: @ShanCarter - could you upgrade your comment to an answer, since it presumably seems to have worked for the OP?  Thanks!